# Firebase Remote Config - android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm currently trying Firebase Remote Config on Android. I gave a parameter a value: 2.2 but when I run an app it prints 2.0 for no reason in Logcat.

here is my code:

initialization:

```
private FirebaseRemoteConfig mRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
```

Setting defaults:

```
mRemoteConfig.setDefaults(hashMap);
```

Fetching:

```
mRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setDeveloperModeEnabled(true).build());
```

Getting double from remote config:

```
double code = mRemoteConfig.getDouble("code");
```

What I have done wrong?

Comment: you need to update ur parameter at Firebase Console as well..Did u do that??

Comment: Yeah, Parameter has value 2.2 but shows 2.0 in Logcat

Comment: Checkout this guide to implement Firebase Remote Config in Android using Kotlin
https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2024/01/firebase-remote-config-android.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the time frame to tell Firebase when to fetch the parameter.

Try code below,below example is fetch update for every 60 seconds:

```
 final FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

 // set in-app defaults
 Map<String, Object> remoteConfigDefaults = new HashMap();
 remoteConfigDefaults.put("CURRENT_VERSION", "2.0");
  //...any other defaults here

 firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults);
 firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(60) // set the value in second to fetch every minutes
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "remote config is fetched.");

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. call `fetch()` to fetch the values from Firebase

**and**

2. call [`activateFetched()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#activateFetched()) to activate the values last fetched, whenever appropriate and convenient in your app.

Only after **both** of those steps are done will you receive the most up-to-date values set in the Firebase Console when you call `getDouble("code")`.

[Example usage from Firebase's Quickstart app on Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/4017aac2bdc591dc8b9702953702f09921a4e76d/config/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/config/java/MainActivity.java#L110-L120)

Comment: Yeah, all I had to do was to add 60 in fetch method: fetch(60) then addOnCompleteListener();